# В предпоследнем слове после каждой буквы вставить символ *

Tags: c

Моя цель:

1. В функцию `zad2()` передать аргумент `s`, который является массивом символов/строкой (`char s[]`).
2. В функции `zad2(char s[])` я нахожу предпоследнее слово в строке и после каждой его буквы вставляю символ `*`.
3. Вернуть обработанную `s` в функцию `main`.

У меня есть следующие функции:
Поиск пробела для выделения слова

```
char* next_to_last(char* str) {
  char* end = &str[strlen(str)];
  while (*end == ' ') end--;
  while (*end != ' ') end--;
  while (*end == ' ') end--;
  while (*end != ' ') end--;
  end++;
  return end;
}
```

Прохождение по слову с использованием первой функции:

```
void zad2() {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    while (printf("Введите строку для задания: ") && fgets(buf, 81, stdin) && *buf!='\n') {
        for(char* word = next_to_last(buf); !strchr(DELIM, *word); word++) {
            for (char* ptr = &word[strlen(word)]; ptr>word; ptr--) {
                *(ptr+1) = *ptr;
            }
            *++word = '*';
        }
        puts(buf);
    }
}
```

Суть проблемы в том, что мне нужно не вводить строку через `fgets()`, как во второй функции, а сразу работать с передаваемой `s` и возвращать её в `main`.

Comment: Суть проблемы непонятна совершенно.  И какое к ней имеет отношение весь приведённый код тоже непонятно. Надо - не вводите строку, а передавайте её аргументом, кто-то мешает?

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что у меня не выходит заменить всю эту байду с buf на свою переменную. Мешает моё незнание, в связи с которым я и прошу помощи.

Comment: Э... `void zad2(char s[], char buf[]) {`. Всё.

Comment: У меня есть глобальная переменная `s`, в которой есть текст. Её мне необходимо передать в функцию `zad2()` для обработки. От `buf` мне нужно как раз избравиться и все измнения производить в `s`.

Comment: Глобальные переменные никуда передавать не надо, их и так видно из функции. Но если принять как данность что глобальные переменные - зло, то переменная `s` передаётся в функцию как обычный параметр: `void zad2(char *s)` или `void zad2(char s[])`. Вы же так передаёте аргумент в `next_to_last()` (про её странность не будем), в чём проблема сделать то же самое?

Comment: Ну так расскажите в чём суть! Вы не знаете как передать строку в функцию аргументом? Так это не сюда, а в учебник...

Comment: Ну, я не понимаю, как итерироваться по строке s, сохранив все эти указатели из функции `zad2()` моего вопроса. Написать `while (*s != '\0')` я не могу, а если через `for`, то и вовсе запутываюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, вот итог изменений:

```
char *zad2(char *buf) {
   buf[80] = 0;
    for(char* word = next_to_last(buf); !strchr(" ", *word); word++) {
        for (char* ptr = &word[strlen(word)]; ptr>word; ptr--) {
            *(ptr+1) = *ptr;
        }
        *++word = '*';
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Затем в `main()` вызывается `out = zad2(some_string_outside)` и выводим через `puts(out)` либо `printf("%s", out)`